# How to set the base path or the ApplicationPath for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application which I want to put behind NGINX reverse proxy. Currently the web application is served from the domain's root, i.e., `http://www.example.com/`, and it works fine.

Now, I am looking to move the application behind NGINX such that the application can be served from something like: `http://www.example.com/myapp/`

I am not able to figure our how to set the base path or the application path of the application to `/myapp` so that the NGINX rule for it would work. The rule I have in NGINX is something like:

```
location /myapp/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7654;
    }
```

I have tried setting `app.UsePathBase("/myapp");` in `Configure` method of my `Startup.cs`, but it did not help. The prefix `/myapp` is not getting added to the links that are served out of my web application. Is it incorrect for me to expect a URL such as `<a href="/foo">Foo</a>` to be automatically treated as `href="/myapp/foo"` when sent to the client?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "The prefix /myapp is not getting added to the links that are served out of my web application" - this is not something your web-server can solve through configuration - you'll need to go through the C# code of your ASP.NET MVC application to ensure that all rendered links, routes and paths have the configured `PathBase` value.

Comment: However, provided you use ASP.NET MVC's built-in URL-generation features (like `Url.Route` and application-root-relative paths in the form `~/foo/bar`) then you won't have much work to do.

Comment: Thank you @Dai. The URLs are not hard-coded, and are relative to the root.

Comment: One solution which has worked for AngularJS based SPA (with ASP.net MVC) is:
1. `app.UsePathBase("/myapp");`
2. Set the `<base href="/myapp/">` on my HTML page. I have only 3 top level HTML including the one holding my AngularJS views.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you have to do :
in the conf file :

```
location /zola/{
   proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/zola/;
}
```

in the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IaaplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UsePathBase("/zola");     
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Publish and run the exe of the web app and restart nginx.
In fact you can set multiple base paths like show below

```
public void Configure(IaaplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UsePathBase("/zola"); 
        app.UsePathBase("/kola");     
        ...
        ...
    }
```